# How to correctly measure critical current density in superconductors?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, electric-current, superconductivity

In my experiments, I measure the *critical currents* of superconductors, and by dividing them by the *cross-section areas*, I derive the *critical current densities*. I've also seen colleagues doing the same thing. But recently I was reminded that the currents in superconductors only flow near the surface, due to the Meissner effect (exponential decay). Then I realize it does not make sense to have the critical current divided by the *cross-section area*, but it should be divided by (*cross-section perimeter* * *penetration depth*) which is the practical region that the current flow through. Am I overthinking here, or I've calculated the critical current density wrongly all the time before?